# Python Celery: Update django model after state change

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I managed to find 2 similar topics with discussion about this issue, but unfortunately I couldn't get what is the best solution from it:

1. [Update Django Model Field Based On Celery Task Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737175/update-django-model-field-based-on-celery-task-status)
2. [Update Django Model Field Based On Celery Task Status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737175/update-django-model-field-based-on-celery-task-status)

I use Django & Celery (+redis as Message broker) and I would like to update django model when celery task status changes(from pending -> success, pending -> failure) etc.

My code:

```
import time

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(name="run_simulation")
def run_simulation(simulation_id: str):
    t1_start = time.perf_counter()
    doSomeWork() # we may change this to sleep for instance
    t1_end = time.perf_counter()
    return{'process_time': t1_end - t1_start}
```

and the particular view from which I am calling the task:

```
def run_simulation(request):
    form = SimulationForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        new_simulation = form.save()
        new_simulation.save()
        task_id = tasks.run_simulation.delay(new_simulation.id)
```

The question is, what is the preferred way to update django model state of Simulation when status of task has been changed?

In the docs I found handlers that are using methods `on_failure`, `on_success` etc. http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#handlers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a preferred method to do something like this since it depends on your project.
You can use a monitoring task like the link you sent. Give the task a task id and re-schedule the task until the monitored task is in its FINISHED state.

```
from celery import AsyncResult

@app.task(bind=True)
def monitor_task(self, t_id):
    """Monitor a task"""
    res = AsyncResult(t_id, backend=self.backend, app=self.app)
    if res.ready():
        raise self.retry(
            countdown=10,
            exc=Exception("Main task not done yet.")
        )
```

You can also create an event receiver and check the state of the task then save it on the DB.
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#real-time-processing

Now, if you are only interested in success and failure states then you can create  success and failure callbacks and the care of saving the success or failure state in the DB there.

```
tasks.run_simulation.apply_async(
    (sim_id,),
    link=tasks.success_handler.s(),
    link_error=tasks.error_handler()
)
```

http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#linking-callbacks-errbacks

Comment: I don't think that a loop checking task status is the best approach. Event receiver is better in that way, but unfortunately I wasn't able to work it out yet. I will be back with result and in case that one of those 2 approaches work, I will accept your answer.

Comment: I meant to re-schedule the task, not to run a blocking loop.
This is how Celery checks for chords when using RPC backend.
It might still get costly but it depends on the setup.
I updated the answer to reflect what I mean.